# Trocando a Culture do sistema

Tags: c#, winforms, culture

Desenvolvendo um sistema para uma empresa Boliviana, em um windows com a culture `pt-BR`, alguns objetos como `datetimepicker` tem seus componentes internos de acordo com a língua em que o sistema foi instalado.

E no meu caso, quando esse sistema foi ser instalado na Bolívia, nenhum windows terá como culture `es-BO`, logo precisaria de uma maneira via código que a troca de culture seja feita para que esses objetos tenham seus componentes com textos em espanhol e não com a culture e que o sistema foi instalado.

De acordo com a documentação http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh(v=vs.110).aspx essa troca de culture deve ocorrer antes dos componentes serem inicializados (`InitializeComponent()`) com as seguintes linhas de código:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-BO");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-BO");
```

Mas mesmo utilizando essa solução, meu resultado continuou sendo os textos do objeto todos em português.
A troca chega a ocorrer mas o sistema "automaticamente" retorna a culture para a inicial? ou estou fazendo essa troca de maneira errada?

Comment: Você quer que os textos específicos do .Net ficam em espanhol? Eles aparecem na sua aplicação? Os textos que você criou para sua aplicação estão ok? Você usou *resources* ou escreveu os textos brutos na aplicação? O .Net instalado nas máquinas está com a localização em espanhol?

Comment: são os textos que dependem da linguagem do sistema, por exemplo, o datetimepicker quando clicado, os seus textos em pt-br seriam, exemplo: "Setembro", "Hoje", "terça feira".

Comment: quero trocar esses textos que dependem da linguagem do sistema

Comment: De imediato só consigo imaginar que há problema no *deploy* do .Net nessas máquinas, possivelmente faltando os *resources* do .Net para `es-BO`. Você sabe quais linguagens estão instaladas na máquina? Tentou outras, inglês, por exemplo?

Comment: mesmo utilizando en-US ele não faz a troca.

Comment: Olha dentro do `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vX.Y.ZZZZZ`. Veja se tem algumas pastas com nome de 4 dígitos. Veja os números que existem lá. O 1033 por exemplo é o `en-US`. Precisa existir para outras línguas. Este é um problema possível. Mas se existir o 1033 e não funcionou com `en-US`, o problema é outro e ainda não consigo imaginar o que poderia ser.

Comment: tem a 1033, e também a 1046, que é provavelmente a pt-BR.

Comment: Isso. Em `es-BO` não vai mostrar mesmo, não existe os arquivos com os textos. Mas ainda me intriga não ter mostrado em inglês. Minha única experiência com isto foi um teste rápido muito tempo atrás e tinha dado certo.

Comment: por enquanto, na minha máquina de testes coloquei o idioma manualmente para Espanhol(Bolívia), ai sim tudo fica da maneira que deveria

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi Só pra eu me localizar: qual a tecnologia da sua aplicação?

Comment: aplicação para desktop, fazendo em windows form mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O fato é que a técnica de alterar a `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` e a `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` não funciona para o controle `DateTimePicker` e para o controle `MonthCalendar`, conforme a explicação da própria Microsoft:

[The DateTimePicker and MonthCalendar control do not reflect the CurrentUICulture property](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;889834&x=18&y=19)

De acordo com o artigo, esses controles levam em conta apenas as configurações do sistema no painel de controle. Assim, para alterá-los, é necessário efetivamente alterar as configurações do sistema inteiro.

Prova disso, é que se você alterar a `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` e a `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`, para `"en-US"`, por exemplo, o controle `NumericUpDown` efetivamente irá respeitar sua escolha, alterando o separador de milhar e de decimal, de acordo.

Assim, pode-se dizer que a técnica funciona para "quase" tudo... exceto para os controles `DateTimePicker` e `MonthCalendar` (e eventualmente outros que estejam atrelados às configurações do sistema).

Answer (score 0):

Minha aplicação apresentava o mesmo problema.
O problema foi solucionado quando eu fiz assim:

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-BO", true);`
`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("es-BO", true);`

Comment: Amanhã chegando no meu PC de trabalho eu já testo e te dou a resposta

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi vai conseguir dormir? :P

Comment: Ok, verifica se isso te ajuda. Qualquer coisa, comente aqui!

Comment: Dormi tranquilo @TiagoCésarOliveira hehehe, e ainda sim não foi, testei até com `en-US`e nem assim