# Entender "," como "." na hora de formatar

Tags: c#, .net, string, formatação, culture

Meu Visual Studio está entendendo um pouco errado o que eu digito (console):

```
using System;

namespace Uri_CSharp
{
    class URI
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double raio = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), area;
            area = Math.Pow(raio, 2) * 3.14159;
            Console.WriteLine("{0:F4}", area);
        }
    }
}
```

Entrada: 2.0 (maneira que eu gostaria de fazer a entrada)

Saída:   1256,6360

Entrada: 2,0

Saída:   12,5664 (maneira que eu gostaria de saída, porém, com . em vez de ,)

Tem onde configurar isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui da seguinte forma:
Primeiro declarei uso desses dois:

```
using.System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
```

Depois antes de começar a imprimir no console, declarei isso:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, [o Visual Studio é só um IDE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101), ele ajuda desenvolver, ele não executada, ele não tem que entender nada.

Segundo, o código executa o que foi mandado fazer, o computador "entende" o que o programador mandou fazer. Quem tem que entender o que está fazendo é o programador.

Tem várias formas de resolver isso. A pergunta não deixa muito claro o que precisa fazer então vou responder o que eu acho que deseja.

É preciso considerar a cultura a ser usada na impressão dele.

Além disso é melhor usar um [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101) já que não se tem certeza que será digitado um valor que pode ser convertido.

Aproveitei e dei uma modernizada no código.

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Uri_CSharp {
    public class URI {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            if (double.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var raio)) {
                double area = Pow(raio, 2) * 3.14159;
                WriteLine(area.ToString("F4", new CultureInfo("pt-BR")));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HSFIaw). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C2zLTf). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Console/FormatNumber.cs).

É possível definir a cultura padrão para uma *thread*, assim o *runtime* passa considerar ele no lugar do que está configurado no computador:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
```

Comment: Essa minha pergunta foi por causa que se eu compilar o mesmo código no site http://repl.it ele passa exatamente como eu quero, já no visual studio instalado no meu PC é diferente, eu imaginava existir uma opção nas propriedades do programa

Comment: Existe no computador. Se não dizer qual é a cultura,o código executará a cultura do computador. Tem que optar em usar a cultura do computador ou uma específica. O *default* é deixar o computador "decidir".

Comment: Eu teria que trocar o idioma do windows?

Comment: Não, só a configuração regional.

Comment: Pode me dizer onde é isso?

Comment: Aliaz, teria uma forma de decidir dentro do código?

Comment: Foi o que eu respondi.

Comment: Porém na sua forma, eu defino sempre que vou converter, teria alguma forma de já deixar definido?

Comment: Deixar definido onde?

Comment: No início do código, por exemplo, já deixar a cultura do jeito que eu defini pra sempre que imprimir já sair da maneira como a cultura deixa

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33564/trocando-a-culture-do-sistema Eu vi esse post, porém, não consegui declarar esse thread, fica aqui como se não existisse

Comment: Coloquei na resposta.

Comment: Não não, errou por pouco ali, a solução que encontrei foi:
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Não é nem CurrentUiCulture nem pt-BR

Comment: O que você vai colocar, depende do que deseja, a pergunta não deixa claro o que deseja.

Answer (score -1):

Voce pode utilizar o Replace, na entrada dos dados, exemplo.

entrada 
    1,200.Replace(",","."); //Tira a virgula e coloca o ponto.
Saida
    1.200

Espero ter ajudado.