# Objeto não reconhece membro

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, funções, label

Tudo o que eu faço é em Python. Uma das funções que tenho que fazer é uma de conversão, onde ela tenta converter o valor do `TextBox` e se der errado, executar o bloco de erro.

```
private void converter(object label)
{
    try
    {
        Convert.ToDouble(label.Text.Replace(".", ","));
    }
    catch
    {
        label.BackColor = Color.Red;
        LBL_ERR.Visible = true;
        LBL_ERR2.Visible = true;
        LBL_ERR2.Text = "VALORES INVÁLIDOS INSERIDOS";
        TXT_Altura.Text = "";
        TXT_Idade.Text = "";
        TXT_Peso.Text = "";
        LBL_IMCR.Text = "";
        LBL_TipoR.Text = "";
        LBL_SitR.Text = "";
        return;
    }
```

O erro está nas variáveis da função. Já tentei usar variável de tipo `string`, `int`, `object` e nada dá certo, ele acusa que a variável `label` não tem nenhum dos métodos requeridos. Que tipo devo usar pra isso dar certo?

Erro acusado:

> ```
> Gravidade Código  Descrição   Projeto Arquivo Linha   Estado de Supressão
> Erro  CS1061  'object' não contém uma definição para 'BackColor' e não foi possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão 'BackColor'
> acessível que aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo 'object' (há uma
> diretiva de uso ou referência de assembly
> ausente?) IMC C:\Users\LABINFO\source\repos\SLN_IMC\IMC\Form1.cs  30  Ativo
> ```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

O tipo a ser recebido no método (e não função) é [`Label`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e não `object`. Isso resolverá esse problema.

O código tem outros problemas. Não deveria trocar ponto por vírgula, deveria usar o [sistema de cultura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141112/101). Não deveria capturar exceção, deveria fazer um [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). E também, não é erro, mas métodos devem ter seus nomes começando em maiúsculo e preferencialmente com um significado maior que este, tem cara que ele nem deveria existir, pelo menos não desta forma. E isso parece um valor monetário, então não deveria ser do tipo `Double` e sim `Decimal`. Isso é um erro em Python também.

Programar em uma linguagem é bem diferente de programar em outra, ao contrário do que as pessoas imaginal, não é porque todas tem `if` que todas são iguais.